# 'this is' or 'these are'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

I have the following sentences.

> 1. This is our first arrival in the UK.
> 2. These are our first arrival in the UK.

I am not sure, which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"This is our first arrival in the UK" is correct.

There is only one arrival under discussion -- your first one -- so the subject is singular. You used the singular word "arrival". Thus a singular verb and pronoun are called for.

If you were talking about multiple arrivals, you would say "these are". Like, "These are arrivals that occurred during 2014."

Comment: These *are* the arrivals that occurred...I think

Comment: @MaulikV Not sure what point you're making. Please clarify.

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure, but maybe he's pointing at using the definite article. (*the* arrivals) IMHO, using or not using the definite article does change the meaning somehow, but one isn't prior to the other.

Comment: @MARamezani If so, the sentence is valid with or without the article, though the meaning is slightly changed. Are we talking about arrivals in general, or some specific set of arrivals?

Comment: Exactly, @MARamezani, the definite article is required because we are talking **specifically** about the arrivals happened in 2014!

Comment: @MaulikV Not necessarily. If we are distinguishing two sets of arrivals, say those that happened in 2014 and those that happened in 2013, then, yes, we'd say "THE arrivals for 2014" and "THE arrivals for 2013". But if we were talking about some other characteristic of arrivals, say, arrivals by plane versus ship, and then we notice that the arrivals by plane were all in 2014, we might say, "These are arrivals that occurred in 2014" without using an article.

Comment: @MaulikV - As Jay points out, should the talk be only about the whole set of arrivals that happened at that time, the definite article isn't needed.

Comment: @MARamezani I'm not sure...but if I'm showing someone the paper that has a list of arrivals happened in *any particular year*, I'd lean toward using the definite article. It's something like The profit or The loss we made in 2014. The arrival we had in 2014 and so on...

Comment: Hmm, @MaulikV I reckon both versions are correct. But Jay's emphasis is on indefiniteness, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to say.

If you are talking about your family arriving to the UK for the first time, you might say

> This **is** our first arrival in the UK.

If you are Theresa May and are greeting initial refugees from Syria, you might say to the press

> These **are** our first arrival**s** in the UK.